# Mocha --watch fails on second run with "addEventListener is not a function"

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I have a typescript project that I test with mocha. For convenience I use the `--watch` flag. When I start mocha, my tests succeed, but after touching a file and triggering mocha to re-run, I receive an exception:

```
TypeError: _a.addEventListener is not a function
```

I created a [small repository](https://github.com/RefusesNames/mocha_watch_fails) to reproduce the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the `sandbox` for all stubs to have a clean state for every test.